# When running my function my if statement is not running

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, if-statement, bubble-sort

I am trying to make a simple bubble sort, and the if statement i'm using to sort the numbers in my array is not running. Can anybody help me get this to run?

Here is my code:

```
def Bubble( a ):
    Flag = False
    while not Flag:
        Flag = True
        for i in range(0, len(a), -1):
            if a[i] > a[i+1]: #this if statement isn't running
                a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
                print("hi")
                Flag = False



def main():
    a = GRN(10)
    acopy = a[:]
    Bubble(a)
    acopy.sort()
    print(a==acopy)
    print(a)
    print(acopy)


main()
```

Comment: Why do you think it isn't running?

Comment: I nested the print statement inside the if statement and it is not printing

Comment: putting a print statement inside the if only proves whether the condition is true, not whether that line of code is running or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`range(0, len(a), -1)` is always an empty list, because the step is negative. It is not the `if` statement to blame, but the `for` loop. What you need is `range(len(a)-1)`.

Comment: when I remove the -1 My list index is out of range

Comment: Perfect thank you! I will upvote as soon as the ten minutes are up.